# How to use getter in string in Java

Tags: java, string, initialization, getter

```
public class Obj{
        int len;
        int id[] = new int[100];
        int pr[] = new int[100];
        /*Constructor*/
        public Obj(int a[], int b[], int l){
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                id[i] = a[i];
            }
            for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                pr[i] = b[i];
            }
            len = l;
        }
        public void setLen(int l){
            len = l;
        }
        public void getLen(int l){
            return len;
        }
        public void setId(int a[]){
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                id[i] = a[i];
            }
        }
        public void setPrice(int b[]){
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                pr[i] = b[i];
            }
        }
        public void sort(){
            int i, j;

            for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                for(j=0;j<len-i-1;j++){
                    if(pr[j]>pr[j+1]){
                        int temp = pr[j];
                        pr[j] = pr[j+1];
                        pr[j+1] = temp;
                        int temp2 = id[j];
                        id[j] = id[j+1];
                        id[j+1] = temp2;
                    }
                }
            }

            for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                System.out.println(id[i]+" "+pr[i]);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Hello, I am new to java and I am trying to intialize my string id and pr to the size of len, but it does not work when i am running it. so i;ve decided to put a constant 100 instead, and the code works properly. Can somebody tell me how can i set the size of my string into the value of len?

in my main class, i call the method setLen first

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it does work like you expect. The loop bodies in your constructor never execute, since `len==0` when they are reached.

Comment: You also need to change the lengths of `pr` and `id` in `setLen`; and you don't need a parameter in `getLen`.

Comment: When you say `string`, don't you really mean `array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor, you should assign a value to `len` *before* you do any calculations with it. And concerning the arrays, initialize them in constructor too.

```
...
int[] id; // more common to write int[] instead of id[]
int[] pr;
...
public Obj(int a[], int b[], int l){
    int i;
    len = l;
    pr = new int[len];
    id = new int[len];
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        id[i] = a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        pr[i] = b[i];
    }
}
```

> in my main class, i call the method setLen first

You can't really call `setLen` *before* constructor

Comment: For the sake of completeness: it would be possible to call `setLen(l);` in the constructor instead of using `len = l;` (it doesn't matter though).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should not use two separate arrays and implicitly assume that they have the same length and that each element of one array corresponds to the element of the other array with the same index.

Better solutions:

- Use a HashMap id => price (might cause an issue with sorting however)
- Use a struct or class containing both id and price and put the objects of this class into the array or another container.

I also recommend to use ArrayList or one of the other collection classes instead of arrays. This would allow you to modify the size later, if required. Also they have built-in sorting.